# How to reference System.Xml.Linq in SQL Server 2008 CLR Object?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, clr, linq-to-xml

I want to create a CLR Stored Procedure for SQL Server 2008 that references the System.Xml.Linq assembly.  According to the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279.aspx) this assembly is safe for use in SQL Server 2008.

However when I attempt to add a reference using Visual Studio 2008 (Team Suite with GDR R2 installed) this assembly is not listed as one of the available assemblies.

Does anyone know how I can add this assembly to a SQL Server CLR project?

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://codebetter.com/blogs/rodpaddock/archive/2007/09/13/accessing-external-assemblies-from-sql-server-clr-stored-procedures.aspx) may help you.

> [...] the “external” assembly must be “pre-deployed” to the server.

Comment: (Note, I am not flagging this yet since it has the key answer, but...) While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: And that link no longer works!